Simplifying a reciprocal of a product of two quadratics using modular arithmetic
This is the fraction I'm trying to simplify mod q: $\frac{1}{(k^{2a} + k^a + 1)(k^{2b} + k^b +1)}$ and we have that $k^5 = 1 \bmod q$, $k ≠ 1 \bmod q$, and that $a$ and $b$ are integers where $a ≠ b$ and are $\bmod 5$ while $q$ is a prime.
From this, I thought we could say that $k^4 + k^3 + k^2 + k + 1 = 0 \bmod q$ and replace that whenever we see that pattern of powers of $k$ to further simplify this but I'm not sure how to expand that into a series. Binomial expansion doesn't seem applicable. Could you please tell me how to go from here?
These terms are summed together $\sum$ $\frac{1}{(k^{2a} + k^a + 1)(k^{2b} + k^b +1)}$ and so a and b are different and a, b is the same as b, a so we consider that the same. So it is the sum of 10 such pairs a and b: {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2,3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you want to simplify mod $5$? Your question doesn't make much sense otherwise, but you should make this clear!

I'm really sorry for the confusion, I want to simplify it mod q

Please put that information in the first paragraph! (Also, use $\bmod$ instead of just $mod$ to improve the layout, getting $1\bmod q$ instead of $1modq$.)

That's better! But I have to say, I don't think your expression can be simplified in any meaningful way. Is there a relation between $a$ and $b$ that you haven't told us about?

a and b are just integers from this set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} hence mod 5, and a ≠ b.

I've added some more context to the problem, where each of these fractions is part of a sum of 10 such fractions.

The sum equals … $5$, independent of $q$! (Of course we must have $q\equiv1\pmod5$ for such a $k$ to exist.) Evidence first, then a proof.
Evidence:

Calculating it by brute force for $q=11,31,41,61,71$ gives $5$ as the answer.
If we replace $k$ by $e^{2\pi i/5}$ and consider the sum over the complex numbers, the answer also simplifies to $5$.

Proof: If we replace $k$ by a variable $x$ and calculate the sum $\sum_{1\le j\le 4} \sum_{0\le i<j} \frac1{(x^{2i}+x^i+1)(x^{2j}+x^j+1)}$ as a rational function, the result is $a(x)/b(x)$ where
\begin{align*}
a(x) &= x^{16}-x^{15}+2 x^{14}+x^{13}+4 x^{12}-2 x^{11}+8 x^{10}+3 x^9 \\
&\qquad{}+11 x^8-4 x^7+23x^6-2 x^5+7 x^4+15 x^3+12 x^2-10 x+22 \\
b(x) &= 3 (x^4-x^2+1)(x^4+x^2+1)^2(x^6+x^3+1).
\end{align*}
We can write the rational function as
$$
\frac{a(x)}{b(x)} = \frac{a(x)(1+x+x^2)}{b(x)(1+x+x^2)} = \frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)\alpha(x)+15}{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)\beta(x)+3}
$$
where $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ are particular polynomials of degree $14$ and $16$, respectively.
Now we can plug in $x=k$, where $k$ is a primitive $5$th root of unity, over any field (of characteristic not equal to $3$). Since $k^4+k^3+k^2+k+1=(k^5-1)/(k-1)=0$ for any such primitive $5$th root of unity, the rational function will then simplify to just $15/3=5$.
(The magic-seeming factor $1+x+x^2$ was chosen because it turns out to be the inverse of $b(x)/3$ modulo $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$.)

THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!
